# Ambari Monitoring raw data

Tags: api, monitoring, ambari

For my masters project, I'm looking for a convenient way to grasp the monitoring data Ambari collects. To be precise, I'm interested in the raw data (can be csv, xml, json, you name it) of the charts Ambari shows in the dashboard, i.e., Cluster CPU, Disk Usage, network usage and Cluster load.

So far, the REST API didn't provide me with much helpful data, while I strongly believe that the data must be somehow accessible if it's plotted in the dashboard graphs...

Any hints are very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't clearly see why this got downvoted, but nevermind. I found the solution myself:

The Ambari Metrics API can deliver the data in question, e.g. CPU load, memory usage, Network bandwith or load factors by sending a `GET` Request to

```
http://<ambari-server>:8080/api/v1/clusters/<cluster-name>?fields=metrics/<metric>[<start>,<end>,<step>]
```

while the metric can be `network`, `cpu`, `cpus`, `load`, `memory` or `procs` and start and end time are given as `epoch` (`date +%s`).